# Find the index of a string in a datagridview row?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to find the index of a string in a `DataGridView` row and here is my code:

```
 DataGridViewRow row = dgvVisual.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().FirstOrDefault(r => (string)r.Cells[0].Value == "9");
```

but the return value of `row` is `null` instead of a `DataGridViewRow`, how to solve this problem?

The Whole code is here:

```
   SqlCommand cmd;
   cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from MyTable , SqlConnection);
     SqlDataReader read;
            read = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (read.Read())
            {
                int ColIndex= int.Parse(read["ColumnName"].ToString()) + 1;
                int RowIndex = -1;
                DataGridViewRow row = dgvVisual.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().FirstOrDefault(r => (string)r.Cells[0].Value == (string)read["ColumnNameB"].ToString().Trim());
                if (row != null)
                    RowIndex = row.Index;
                DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chkbxCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dgvVisual[ColIndex, RowIndex];
                chkbxCell.Value = true;

            }
            read.Close();
```

Problem solved as there was some problem in the database and the read back was not correct.

Comment: Didn't understand your question. This would already give you a row.

Comment: modified, changed index to DataGridViewRow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns null because of `FirstOrDefault()`, which means that it didn't find any results with your query. Ensure that you really have any rows with that condition.

Without seeing your data it's hard to say if your lambda query is right.

Comment: i checked that there are rows in the datagridview

Comment: Please provide an example of your data: e.g. rows that you think will satisfy a condition for your query.

Comment: expected result: row.Index = 8 (string)read["ColumnNameB"].ToString().Trim() = 8

Comment: Are you sure that `r.Cells[0].Value` (value in first column) have value `8`? Have you checked it in a debugger?

Comment: Just found out the the value should be "08" instead of "8", problem was solved by modifying database.